# On Kolmogorov complexity of first and last half of a string

Tags: logic, computer-science, computability, kolmogorov-complexity, descriptive-complexity

Denote by $C(x)$ the plain Kolmogorov complexity of $x$ and let $x$ satisfy
$C(x) \ge n - O(1)$ with $n = |x|$. If $x = yz$ with $|y| = |z|$ show that $C(y), C(z) \ge n/2 - O(1)$.

Any ideas how to solve this? If I can construct a Turing machine which just uses a shortest program for one of the strings $y$ or $z$, for example $y$, and an input of length at most $n/2$ to produce $x$ then the problem would be solved, as then $C(x) \le C(y) + n/2$ and so $C(y) \ge C(x) - n/2 = n - O(1) - n/2 = n/2 - O(1)$. But I have no idea how such an algorithm should work?

This is [Exercise 2.2.2 (a)](https://books.google.de/books?id=LKEmB_GQ53QC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PA116#v=onepage&q&f=false) from *An Introduction to Kolmogorov Complexity and Its Applications*.

Comment: Try the algorithm that first computes $y$ and prints it, and then prints $z$. Since $z$ has length $n/2$, the instruction "then print $z$" has length only $(n/2)+O(1)$.

Comment: That's intuitively clear and simple, but what I have problems with is make this formal. My try, let $U$ be the universal Turing machine such that $C = C_U$, and let $T^z$ be a TM which runs $U$ on its input and then prints $z$, so if $U(p) = y$ then $T^z(p) = U(p)z = yz = x$. So now consider some enumeration $T_1, T_2, \ldots$, then $T^z = T_k$ for some $k$. Then I can put this information, i.e. the $k$ in some way in the input for $U$ together with the program $p$, and hence $C(x) \le \mbox{length for coding }k + C(y)$. By this enumeration  the way $z$ is hardcoded into $T_k$ gets lost...

Comment: I think you want to arrange for the input to encode both the program for computing $y$ and the string $z$. Unfortunately, you can't just concatenate them; you need to tell the machine where the one ends and the other starts.  That can be done with a logarithmic number of additional bits, to tell how long the first part of the concatenation is. I don't immediately see a way to avoid that additional $\log n$.

Comment: Yes,okay if this is not possible I need to hardcode it. But how to encode this into a TM just using $n/2$ additional bits? I can modify a TM by adding enough states and tupels to print $z$ at the end, but in each bit based encoding I can think of this needs more then $n/2$ bits (because for example  the encoding need to be self-delimiting between tupels or if I fix the size of an encoded tupel it depends on the number of tupels). The problem is similar if you suppose you can just print one token a time, then "print z" is not possbile, instead "print z_1,,...,print z_k" has length $7\cdot n/2$.

Comment: You don't need to code for a Turing machine; you need to code for a universal machine.  Notice first that there is a non-universal (in fact very far from universal) machine that just prints its input. For this ridiculous machine, the length of a program that prints z is just the length of z.  Therefore, a universal machine must have a program that prints z and has length bounded by the length of z plus a constant.

Comment: With your comment you wanna say $C(u) \le |u| + c$ for some constant $c$ (depending maybe on the ridiculous copy machine)? For the problem, consider a TM $T$ which first computes $y$ and then appends a copy of its input at the end of $y$, then $C_T(yz) \le |z|$ ($C_T$ denotes complexity w.r.t. to $T$). So that with respect to the universal TM we have $C(yz) \le C_T(yz) + c_T \le |z| + c_T$, do you mean that? But then the complexity of computing $y$ is somehow hidden in the constant $c_T$, which depends on $T$ but we can not say that $c_T \le C(y)$, but we want $C(yz) \le |z| + C(y)$??